# Project Server 2010 unable to install over SharePoint Enterprise 2010

Tags: project-server

I installed SharePoint Enterprise 2010 trial version and later tried to install Project Server 2010 but encountered with the below error.

[image]

The Project Server 2010 is also trial version. I tried to install this Project Server several times but did not succeeded because of the above error.

Any ideas why Project Server is unable to detect SharePoint Enterprise 2010. I have successfully installed and configured SharePoint Enterprise 2010 trail on my server.

Answer (score 1):

I have reached the conclusion and found the solution. The Project Server 2010 only installs over SharePoint Enterprise CAL trial version where as me and my members were trying to install Project Server over SharePoint Server 2010 Internet, Enterprise trial version.

When I learned this, I removed existing SharePoint Server 2010 Internet, Enterprise trial version and installed SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise CAL trial version. After that the Project Server 2010 installed successfully.

So we must make sure whenever we install Project Server 2010 we must have SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise CAL only.

I have also confirmed this on Microsoft Project Server web site:
[image]

The above image is an extract from:
http://www.microsoft.com/project/en-us/project-server-faqs.aspx

Comment: I ve installed SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise CAL trial version but still receive the same error. I m running it on Windows Server 2012 trial.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Enterprise features are turned on.

[Same problem discussed here :)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/projectserver2010general/thread/0a4b190c-88b2-444c-b723-a88b20393d9e/)